# MySQL source command and transactions

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using MySQL client:

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.32 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Basically I don't understand the difference between running a script SQL in these ways:

Work properly with transactions, I mean rollback everything if there is an error:

scenario 1:

```
# mysql --show-warnings --verbose -u root -p < script.sql
```

Execute everything even if we have an error in the middle:

scenario 2:

```
mysql> source script.sql
```

My script is basically like this:

```
Start transaction

update 1 (ok)

update 2 (error)

commit
```

I'm expecting to get a rollback if I have an error in the middle of the transaction (update 2) but that doesn't happen if I use `source script.sql`

script.sql

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
       
    UPDATE onboarding.components_options
        SET value = 'Business Details​'
        WHERE component_id = (select id from onboarding.components where reference = 'BUSINESS_ENTITY')
            and type = 'title';
           
    UPDATE onboarding.components_options
        SET value2 = 'Is your business incorporated?​'
        WHERE component_id = (select id from onboarding.components where reference = 'BUSINESS_ENTITY')
            and type = 'subtitle';
           
COMMIT;
```

**scenario 1 (work fine)**

```
# mysql --show-warnings --verbose -u root -p < script.sql
Enter password: 
--------------
START TRANSACTION
--------------
--------------
UPDATE onboarding.components_options
        SET value = 'Business Details​'
        WHERE component_id = (select id from onboarding.components where reference = 'BUSINESS_ENTITY')
            and type = 'title'
--------------
--------------
UPDATE onboarding.components_options
        SET value2 = 'Is your business incorporated?​'
        WHERE component_id = (select id from onboarding.components where reference = 'BUSINESS_ENTITY')
            and type = 'subtitle'
--------------
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 8: Unknown column 'value2' in 'field list'
bash-4.4# mysql -u root -p
```

**scenario 2 (unexpected result, at least for me)**

Pay attention, the commit sentence is executed -> 4

```
mysql> source script.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'value2' in 'field list'
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: "enter image description here" sort of means "replace me with relevant text" and screenshots < copied text... 
Besides that  -please clarify your question...

Comment: @JoSSte sorry bro, I edited everything a few minutes ago

Comment: have you tried dumping `autocommit` value in the different scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `mysql` in [batch mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/batch-mode.html) (`mysql --show-warnings --verbose -u root -p < script.sql`), by default the script will stop processing when an error occurs. So, when your third statement is executed and produces an error, the script (and session) will end and the transaction is implicitly rolled back. You can change this behaviour by passing the [--force](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_force) option to mysql client on the command line.

When you execute your statements using [`source`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45463729338528) the script continues after an error occurs, thus running your `COMMIT` statement and the changes persist.

This functionality has been *questioned* in [feature requests in the past](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35634).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link. 
I read it but it seems nothing happened after march 2012. 
Don't you think this is a weird behaviour? (even if it works as expected)

Comment: @Axel I have never had reason to use `source`, so never given it any thought.